# ML-KIT Text recognision for non english language

Tags: google-mlkit

I am trying to build a Japanese ocr using Google ML-Kit.
It is working for english but for Japanese I don't have the luck.
Can you please provide an example to do the same?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The current Text Recognition in ML Kit does not support non-English languages, but we are adding more languages support including Japan, which should be available in a couple of releases.